# How to assign random interior color of cells as I add names to a list?

Tags: excel, vba, list, random, colors

This is my first time posting so please have mercy!
I have tried to assign random colors to a name list so I can later recall and populate another list of a staffing sheet.

This is my code so far but it doesn't work for some odd reason.
I'm not sure if someone already asked this question but my search has turned up empty handed.

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set WF = Application.WorksheetFunction
    If Target.Cells.Column = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 3 Then
            x = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            x = WF.Match(Target.Value, _
                Range("C1").Resize(Target.Row - 1), _
                0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If x > 0 Then
                ' duplicate value...copy the old color
                Target.Interior.Color = Cells(x, 3).Interior.Color
            Else
                ' choose a new color
                Target.Interior.Color = RGB( _
                    WF.RandBetween(0, 255), _
                    WF.RandBetween(0, 255), _
                    WF.RandBetween(0, 255))
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does target actually have .column = 1 and .column=3 properties? Didn't think that was possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use Application.WorksheetFunction.Match or WorksheetFunction.Match. Use Application.Match and pass the result back to a variant type var which can be checked with IsError without breaking anything.
2. Don't use `On Error Resume Next` if you can easily avoid it. See #1.
3. Declare your vars. Better yet, go into the VBE's Tools, Options and put a check beside Require variable declaration. This will put Option Explicit at the top of every new code sheet. After that has been enabled, go and put `Option Explicit` at the top of every existing code sheet.
4. Target could easily be more than a single cell and your routine will fail if it is. Apply some error control and deal with a Target that is more than a single cell.
5. I honestly do not understand how Target.Cells.Column = 1 and Target.Column = 3 at the same time so I'll just work with the latter since you are trying to match that column.
6. In your case, you can look for the target value in the entire column and it will always be found. If it is found in a row above the target, then you have a duplicate value.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(3)) Is Nothing Then
           Dim t As Range, x As Long
           For Each t In Intersect(Target, Columns(3))
               Debug.Print t.Address(0, 0)
               'looking in the entire column means it will ALWAYS be found
               x = Application.Match(t.Value, Columns(3), 0)
               If x < t.Row Then
                   ' duplicate value...copy the old color
                   t.Interior.Color = Cells(x, 3).Interior.Color
               Else
                   ' choose a new color
                   t.Interior.Color = RGB( _
                       Application.RandBetween(0, 255), _
                       Application.RandBetween(0, 255), _
                       Application.RandBetween(0, 255))
               End If
           Next t
       End If
   End Sub
   ```